# How to do a complexity analysis from the below code with `if-else` statements?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, time-complexity, analysis

I'm trying to find out what is the complexity of this code:

```
///Note: a[i] is an array with n elements

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (Math.random() > 0.25)
       if (i%4 == 0)
        BubbleSort (a[i]);
       else
        QuickSort (a[i]);
  else
   for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
     for (int k = i; k < n; k++)
       BinarySearch (a[i]);
}
```

from my understanding, `BubbleSort` is `n^2`, `QuickSort` best case is `nlogn` but the worst case is `n^2`, and `BinarySearch` is `logn` but requires the list to be sorted.

Going through the code **25%** of the time it'll do a binary search and the other times it will either do `QuickSort` or `BubbleSort` in the section.

It'll have 1/4 chance of doing `BubbleSort` and 3/4 chance to do `QuickSort`.

To find the complexity, would I have to make separate equations for the best case and worst case?

Answer (score 1):

Since complexity is a **class of functions** and not a function itself, you can calculate complexity for all your branches scenarios and consider the worst case.

Just for illustrating, let's consider you have 75% chance of the complexity be O(n) [best scenario] and 25% of complexity be O(n^2) [worst scenario]. You could think like:

```
0.75 * O(n) + 0.25 * O(n^2)
0.75 * c1 * n + 0.25 * c2 * n^2
c3 * n + c4 * n^2    (c3 = 0.75 c1 , c4 = 0.25 c2)
```

but `c3 * n + c4 n^2` is inside the class O(n^2)